# Using an IndexedSeq of monitors or locks in scala

Tags: scala, concurrency

I have a mutable array into which I have two types of calls:

```
def write(content, index): Unit
def read(index): Content
```

I want to have a `synchronized` block that ensures that a `read` following a `write` will return the same contents that were just written:

```
<something>.synchronized {
  write(content, index)
  require(content == read(index))
}
```

I also need to have parallelism so that multiple threads can access different indexes concurrently. Obviously, I can achieve the same functionality with an array of locks, but using `lock` and `unlock` seems like overkill since `synchronized` blocks are simpler, and using something like:

```
val monitors = (0 until n).map(i => i.toString)
...
monitors(index).synchronized {
  write(content, index)
  require(content == read(index))
}
```

or even

```
val monitors = (0 until n).map(_ => new Object)
...
monitors(index).synchronized {
  write(content, index)
  require(content == read(index))
}
```

seems a little like a hack. Is there a better way in Scala?

Answer (score 0):

The most popular way to do concurrent programming in Scala is using Akka. If you need multiple concurrent reads and exclusive writes, a simple way to achieve this is through [Agents](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0/scala/agents.html).

In your particular case, you could have an array of Agents. A benefit that you would gain from this is that the array itself can be immutable, since it will be the individual agents that will take care of the changes to the values.